# What is dart equivalent to kotlin's or java's collection.removeall?

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart

what is the equivalent of kotlin or java's `Collection.removeAll((elements: Collection<E>)`. i only saw that removeWhere method on dart and it does not meet my needs

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove-all.html

> abstract fun removeAll(elements: Collection): Boolean
> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in the specified collection.
> Return true if any of the specified elements was removed from the collection, false if the collection was not modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent at the moment. You could make an extension to add this behavior:

```dart
extension ListRemove<E> on List<E> {
  void removeAll(Iterable<E> iterable) {
    this.removeWhere((e) => iterable.contains(e));
  }
}
```

This code uses `List`s existing `removeWhere` method and removes if the other iterable contains the element.